# Running sum with missing dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, cumulative-sum

I have a table of data like this:

```
PeriodYearMonth Reg      PartNo             ComponentRemovals   RunningRemovals
2019 10         G-NHVP   109-0740V01-137    1                    1
2019 11         G-NHVP   109-0740V01-137    1                    2  
2019 12         G-NHVP   109-0740V01-137    1                    3
2020 01         G-NHVP   109-0740V01-137    1                    4
2019 10         OO-NSF   11-13354P          1                    1
2019 09         G-NHVR   11-13354P          2                    2 
2019 10         OY-HMV   11-13354P          1                    1
```

In the last column I calculated the 7-month running sum of removals per PartNo and per Reg. To do this I made the following code:

```
/****** Find Running Component Removals ******/
SELECT  [PeriodYearMonth]
      ,[Reg]
      ,[PartNo]
      ,[ComponentRemovals]
      ,sum(sum(ComponentRemovals)) over (Partition by [Reg], PartNo Order By PeriodYearMonth, PeriodYearMonth rows between 6 preceding and current row) as RunningRemovals
      ,[ConfirmedFailures]
      , sum(sum(ConfirmedFailures)) over (Partition by [Reg], PartNo Order By PeriodYearMonth, PeriodYearMonth rows between 6 preceding and current row) as RunningFailures

  FROM [RALNHVTST].[dbo].[vtRelRepComponentsRemovalsByPartNo]

  Group by Reg, PartNo, ComponentRemovals, ConfirmedFailures, PeriodYearMonth
  Order by PartNo
```

However, since not all months are included in the PeriodYearMonth column the results are incorrect. I've seen solutions online for simple cases, but the tricky part for me is, that I need an entry for every PartNo, every Reg and every month.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Build and populate a table of all the year-months. Left outer join it to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to create separate derived tables of all the `PeriodYearMonth` values (generated using a recursive CTE) and the distinct `Reg` and `PartNo` pairs, and `CROSS JOIN` them to each other to get all combinations of the columns. This combined table can then be `LEFT JOIN`ed to the original table to get the `ComponentRemovals` for each `Reg`, `PartNo` and `PeriodYearMonth`, and these can then be summed using a window function:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(REPLACE(MIN(PeriodYearMonth), ' ', '-'), '-01'), 23)  AS date, 
         CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(REPLACE(MAX(PeriodYearMonth), ' ', '-'), '-01'), 23)  AS max_date
  FROM vtRelRepComponentsRemovalsByPartNo
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, date), max_date
  FROM CTE
  WHERE date < max_date
)
SELECT FORMAT(CTE.date, 'yyyy MM') AS PeriodYearMonth
     , rp.Reg
     , rp.PartNo
     , COALESCE(v.ComponentRemovals, 0) AS ComponentRemovals
     , SUM(COALESCE(v.ComponentRemovals, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY rp.Reg, rp.PartNo ORDER BY FORMAT(CTE.date, 'yyyy MM')
                                                   ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RunningRemovals
FROM CTE
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Reg, PartNo FROM vtRelRepComponentsRemovalsByPartNo) rp
LEFT JOIN vtRelRepComponentsRemovalsByPartNo v
       ON v.PeriodYearMonth = FORMAT(CTE.date, 'yyyy MM')
      AND v.Reg = rp.Reg
      AND v.PartNo = rp.PartNo
ORDER BY rp.Reg, rp.PartNo, CTE.date
```

Output

```
PeriodYearMonth     Reg     PartNo              ComponentRemovals   RunningRemovals
2019 09             G-NHVP  109-0740V01-137     0                   0
2019 10             G-NHVP  109-0740V01-137     1                   1
2019 11             G-NHVP  109-0740V01-137     1                   2
2019 12             G-NHVP  109-0740V01-137     1                   3
2020 01             G-NHVP  109-0740V01-137     1                   4
2019 09             G-NHVR  11-13354P           2                   2
2019 10             G-NHVR  11-13354P           0                   2
2019 11             G-NHVR  11-13354P           0                   2
2019 12             G-NHVR  11-13354P           0                   2
2020 01             G-NHVR  11-13354P           0                   2
2019 09             OO-NSF  11-13354P           0                   0
2019 10             OO-NSF  11-13354P           1                   1
2019 11             OO-NSF  11-13354P           0                   1
2019 12             OO-NSF  11-13354P           0                   1
2020 01             OO-NSF  11-13354P           0                   1
2019 09             OY-HMV  11-13354P           0                   0
2019 10             OY-HMV  11-13354P           1                   1
2019 11             OY-HMV  11-13354P           0                   1
2019 12             OY-HMV  11-13354P           0                   1
2020 01             OY-HMV  11-13354P           0                   1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d255b/17)

Note that if *all* `PeriodYearMonth` values of interest are present in `vtRelRepComponentsRemovalsByPartNo` you can simply use a `SELECT DISTINCT ...` subquery to get those values rather than the recursive `CTE` e.g.

```
SELECT d.PeriodYearMonth
     , rp.Reg
     , rp.PartNo
     , COALESCE(v.ComponentRemovals, 0) AS ComponentRemovals
     , SUM(COALESCE(v.ComponentRemovals, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY rp.Reg, rp.PartNo ORDER BY d.PeriodYearMonth
                                                   ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RunningRemovals
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PeriodYearMonth FROM vtRelRepComponentsRemovalsByPartNo) d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Reg, PartNo FROM vtRelRepComponentsRemovalsByPartNo) rp
LEFT JOIN vtRelRepComponentsRemovalsByPartNo v
       ON v.PeriodYearMonth = d.PeriodYearMonth
      AND v.Reg = rp.Reg
      AND v.PartNo = rp.PartNo
ORDER BY rp.Reg, rp.PartNo, d.PeriodYearMonth
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d255b/21)

Comment: This is great thanks!
I'm getting the error: 'Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CS_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the concat operation.'
I've had this before but I don't see how to resolve it here. I Only see one colum (PeriodYearMonth) in the concat operation. Any idea what other variable I need to change to resolve this?

Comment: You can ignore that. I solved it by Collating in the exoression.

Comment: @CathalClavie sorry I wasn't around to answer your comment but I'm glad you figured it out yourself and that this gave you the results you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

> In the last column I calculated the running sum of removals per PartNo and per Reg over the past 7 months.

Removing the windowing clause and filter:

```
select [PeriodYearMonth], [Reg], [PartNo], [ComponentRemovals],
        sum(sum(ComponentRemovals)) over (Partition by [Reg], PartNo Order By PeriodYearMonth, PeriodYearMonth) as RunningRemovals
        [ConfirmedFailures],
        sum(sum(ConfirmedFailures)) over (Partition by [Reg], PartNo Order By PeriodYearMonth, PeriodYearMont) as RunningFailures
from [RALNHVTST].[dbo].[vtRelRepComponentsRemovalsByPartNo]
where PeriodYearMonth >= format(dateadd(month, -7, getdate()), 'yyyy MM')
group by Reg, PartNo, ComponentRemovals, ConfirmedFailures, PeriodYearMonth
Order by PartNo
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this doesn't solve my issue. I should've said 7-month running sum rather than 'over the past 7 months.'

Comment: @CathalClavie . . . That was rather ambiguous.  The original phrasing really sounded like the last seven months.